# Taguchi Crossed Array Design Creation and Analysis

Tags: r, experiment-design, computational-statistics

I am trying to create the following Taguchi Crossed Array Design in R.
[image]

```
Table12.1Inner <- FrF2::FrF2(nruns = 8,  generators = "ABC", randomize = FALSE)
Table12.1Outer <- DoE.base::fac.design(nlevels = 2,  nfactors=1, factor.names = "E", randomize = FALSE)
Error in fac.design(nlevels = c(4)) : 
  one factor only is not covered by fac.design

DoE.base::cross.design(Table12.1Inner, Table12.1Outer)
```

So unable to create outer array design. Would highly appreciate if someone help me. Thanks in advance.